# Qt application not resizing properly

Tags: qt4, qt-creator

I am having a problem with resizing my gui's made from Qt.
In full screen basically they don't scale to the available space.

**Here is what i did.**

**1. Created a gui from Qt Designer**.
[image: See here]

**2. When i preview it and try to maximize it, it scales badly. The same thing happens when i use this generated code for my application(it scales badly when maximized)** 
[image: see here]
[image: and here]

**Question:**
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a layout for your your main window and then add spacers 
in the main layout to keep things floating nicely.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/designer-manual.html

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/designer-layouts.html

Comment: i get it. I wasn't setting a toplevel layout. Thanks for the second link. :)

Answer (score 1):

Give the whole widget a `grid layout`so it knows how to resize.

Comment: It has worked. But i had given the whole widget a Horizontal Box layout but it wasn't working. Any reason why?

Comment: The grid layout worked. I was only wondering why my other attempts had failed. But i now get it, i wasn't setting a top level layout.

Comment: You didn't set horizontal layout to widget, You added horizontal layout to main widget (as you add widgets without layout). That's why it didn't work. Remember that you can add layouts to layouts, and also add layouts without layouts ;)